# but it's out there

Tags: meaning-in-context

1. People are still uncomfortable around Muslims. We don't talk about it but it's **out there**.
2. The truth hurts but it's **out there**.
3. True love is hard to find but it's **out there**.

I don't quiet understand the meaning of 'out there' in these sentences. All these sentences were written by me so they might be wrong. But I've definitely heard people using 'out there' this way.

Comment: Imagine this: you are inside a house and someone asks you "where is my football?". You point outside and say "it's out there!". They can go out and find this football. In the same way - something like "true love is hard to find but it's out there" conveys that even though you may not see it now - you can **go find it**. It's out there for you to go and find. It's possible to go and see it for yourself

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose - I think that should be an answer.

Comment: @chasly-reinstateMonica should I post it as an answer?

Comment: Yes, you should post it as an answer.  Don't post answers as comments.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine this: you are inside a house and someone asks you "where is my football?". You point outside and say "it's out there!". They can go out and find this football. In the same way - something like "true love is hard to find but it's out there" conveys that even though you may not see it now - you can **go find it**. It's out there for you to go and find. It's possible to go and see it for yourself

Comment: I see. What about 1. Does it mean that we don't talk about people being uncomfortable around Muslims but it exists in the society. Would it sound natural if I say it standing outdoors?